# Can a moderator prevent my answer from becoming a CW?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I'm still writing my answer to [Is there a canon explanation for how Proton Torpedoes were able to turn 90 degrees at the end of Star Wars: ANH](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/is-there-a-canon-explanation-for-how-proton-torpedoes-were-able-to-turn-90-degre/8559) but I've hit 9 edits already.

I keep finding new bits and pieces across the SW universe to add to the answer, but if I make one more edit it will become a Community Wiki :(

Can a moderator fix the answer to prevent this from happening?

I've tried flagging the question, but I've not seen any response from any mods. Thanks!

Comment: Remember what granny told you. If you pick at it, you'll only make it worse.

Comment: No, they can only reverse it when it goes CW (AFAIK).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatic conversion of answers to community wikis [has been removed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/?cb=1), so this should not be an issue moving forward.

From the blog:

> Therefore, **we have removed all automatic Wiki conversion triggers from the software.** No longer will answers with more than some arbitrary number of edits, or questions with more than a page of answers suddenly lose their owners. To handle those rare situations where unusual activity levels may indicate misuse, we’ve added some new moderator flags in these scenarios: they can respond when necessary by closing or locking the post – but when there is no fire behind the smoke, they can silently dismiss the flag without disruption.

Authors and Mods can convert answers into Community Wikis, but the system will no longer do so automatically.

Answer (score 6):

First, you've only made 8 edits (revision 9), so you have one more before the next makes it CW.

A moderator can only undo CW, not prevent it. The auto-CW is primarily intended to prevent users from making periodic edits to bump their posts so they get more votes. You have clearly not been abusing it in that manner, so if you trigger CW, flag it and a mod will probably undo it.

That said, a few of those edits were fairly small and inconsequential. If you're going to be making a lot of edits, try to coalesce the ones that don't really add necessary information into those that do.

Comment: Do all edits by all users count towards the CW trigger, or does it count each user separately?

Comment: There is a separate trigger for non-OP edits. If 5 distinct other users edit the answer it becomes cw.